# Spatial matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a “cubic” matrix exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73144/does-a-cubic-matrix-exist)

There is some theory about spatial matrices ?, for example matrices of order $3\times 3\times 3 ,A=(a_{ijk}),i,j,k=1,2,3$ where $A$ would be a cube in space with entries inside the cube.

[image]

For example if $f:\mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $f\in C^3$

$f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a).h+\frac{1}{2}f''(a).h^2+\frac{1}{6}f'''(a).h^3+r(h)$ , $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{r(h)}{||h||^3}}=0$ where $f'''(a)$ would be a spatial matrix of order $3\times3$ (application symmetric trilinear).

$f'''(a)=(\frac{\partial^3 f}{x_ix_jx_k}),i,j,k=1,2,3$
$f'''(a):\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$f'''(a)(x,y,z)=\langle (x^t.f'''(a)).y,z\rangle$
Where $x^t.f'''(a)$ would be the multiplication of each plane matrix of the spatial matrix by the vector $x$ resulting in a plane matrix.

Comment: Please take a look at [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) on the reasons for accepting answers.

Comment: [This thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/73144/5363) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

These triply-indexed objects are not considered as "matrices" but rather tensors.